# Python Matplotlib ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

[image: Data Frame[1]

Hi,
how do i plot the Attached Dataframe in python, i am looking for multiple series line graph.

Any help will be much appreciated.

> Error:-ValueError: could not convert string to float

Thanks

Comment: You need to explicitly convert the string to floats, show your code and we might be able to help.

Comment: I have converted above table as dataframe which was in csv earlier and plotted as below:  
d1=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
plt.plot(d1)

Comment: No, you haven't.  Pandas doesn't know how to convert your strings in your csv to floats, because of the extraneous elements - in this case, the % signs.  As a result, it is leaving them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that the % signs in your csv file are making Pandas read each value as a string object, rather than as a float.

The best option for resolving this would probably be to not have extraneous characters like %s everywhere in your csv file.  Instead, it would probably make more sense to list units in your columns, or elsewhere in descriptions.

However, in this case, it can also be solved afterward by removing the extraneous characters and converting manually, eg, for a DataFrame `a`:

```
a.ix[:,a.dtypes==object] = a.ix[:,a.dtypes==object].applymap(lambda x: float(x[:-1]))
```

This will work for your specific case of one % at the end being the offending character consistently:

- The indexing here selects all columns that are of dtype 'object', which in this case are all strings with the last character %.
- The lambda function that is applied to each element removes the last character from the string, and then converts it to a float.
- It is then assigned to the same columns.

Comment: It really works,you are simply great, thanks a lot for your prompt response.. Much much appreciated